# Launch eclipse product in shared directory

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I deployed an Eclipse product and it works great in my computer, in order to everybody in my network could use it I left it in a shared directory, at first nobody but me could run it then I noticed that in the application.ini file there are some arguments that are pointing to libraries that are in my computer, I fixed it copying these libraries at the root folder of the aplication and changing this arguments in the file and it worked but with errors, those error are because the config.ini file has the variable osgi.framework pointing to the eclipse directory that I have in my computer then again I tried to copy these libraries to the application's root folder but it can't launch the application because it is not reading that osgi.framework variable.

Currently is something like this:

```
osgi.framework=file\:/D\:/personal/Apps/eclipse-jee-mars-M2-win32/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/312/data/1012924256/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.10.100.v20140909-1314.jar
```

I tried to change it after I moved those libraries to the application folder to something like:

```
osgi.framework=file\:/\\shareddirectory\/application/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.10.100.v20140909-1314.jar
```

But it doesn't work.

There is a correct way to make an eclipse product usable from shared directory or a least making portable? there is totally another way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try putting `@user.home` in your products .ini file.

Something like:

```
-configuration
@user.home/<datadir>/config
-data
@user.home/<datadir>/workspace
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Eclipse multi-user installs](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fmulti_user_installs.html) manual page. It might have solutions to your problem.